# Shape that balances isoperimetric ratio with invisibility

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

I seek a two-dimensional shapes $S$, bounded by a Jordan curve,
that optimally balances its isoperimetric ratio $r(S)$
against what I call its invisibility index $iv(S)$.
Define the *isoperimetric ratio* $r(S)$ of $S$ to be
$4 \pi A / L^2$, where $A$ is the area of $S$ and $L$ its
perimeter. This ratio is in $(0,1]$
and achieves $1$ for $S$ a disk.
See, e.g., the
[Wikipedia article on the isoperimetric inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality).
Define *invisibility index* $iv(S)$
to be the probability that that a pair $(x,y)$ of random points
in $S$ 
(chosen uniformly and independently)
are invisible to one another in the sense that
the segment $xy$ includes a point strictly exterior to $S$.
($iv(S)$ is $1$ minus the 
[Beer convexity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.1769) of $S$.)

> **Q**. What shape (or shapes) $S$ maximize the product
>   $P(S) = r(S) \cdot iv(S)$?

If $S$ is a disk, $r(S)=1$ and $iv(S)=0$ so $P(S)=0$.
If $S$ is a thin spiral, then $r(S)$ approaches $0$
and $iv(S)$ approaches $1$ so $P(S)$ approaches $0$.
In between, $P(S) > 0$.

I've computed $P(S)$ for the very narrow class of
symmetric `L`s, unit squares with a square removed
from one corner, as illustrated below.

---

[image: TwoLs]

          

<sup>Two symmetric `L`s with different parameters $a$. Origin at lowerleft corner.</sup>

---

These shapes are determined by one parameter $a$ as illustrated.
Among this class of shapes, it appears that the maximum 
product $P(S)$ is achieved when $a \approx \frac{1}{4}$,
the left shape above. Plots $r(\,)$, $iv(\,)$, and $P(\,)$
are shown below. 
The isoperimetric ratio for a square is $r(1) = \pi/4 \approx 0.79$.

---

[image: IsoInvisibGraph]

          

<sup>Red: $r(a)$. Blue: $iv(a)$. Green: Product $P(a)$.</sup>

---

**Update**. Seems like Gerhard Paseman's figure-8
[image: Fig8], with $r=\frac{1}{2}$, $iv=\frac{1}{2}$, $P=\frac{1}{4}$,
is the extreme shape. (In comments I mistakenly said $iv=\frac{1}{4}$.)

Comment: Does a (shape approximating a) figure 8 shape have measure (approaching) 1/4?  Gerhard "Unsure Of The Numerical Calculation" Paseman, 2017.02.08.

Comment: If you mean the union of two just touching disks, then I think the isoperimetric ratio is $1/2$: For unit-radius disks, perimeter $L=4\pi$, area $A=2\pi$, ratio $1/2$. And the invisibility index would be $1/4$.

Comment: That might be the limiting figure, but the intermediate figures would be like barbells with small twisty handles.  Except for necklace or beaded string shapes, I doubt I can improve much on that measure.  Gerhard "Needs Coffee Before Needing Pearls" Paseman, 2017.02.08.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Nice hypothesis that the figure-8 is the limiting shape.

Comment: If we consider $r(S)$ to be a measure of disk-ness of $S$, and $iv(S)$ to be a measure of nonconvexity, then you seem to be seeking _the most nonconvex disk_ :P

Comment: I'd go for a cardioid-like shape -maybe with a longer cusp

Comment: For the L-shapes above with $a<1/2$, we have $A=2a(1-a)+a^2$, $L=4$, 
$$iv = \frac{2-4a+a^2-a^2\log(\frac{1}{a}-1)}{(2-a)^2}.$$
So their maximum is actually quite close to $a=2/7$, with $P=.113$.

Comment: @MattF.: My simulation shows that graph reaches about $P=0.114$, in close agreement with your calculation.

Answer (score 2):

A **Pacman** is a good candidate.

Take a unit circle and cut out a sector with angular width $\alpha$.  Then:

\begin{align}
A &= \pi - \frac{\alpha}{2}\\
L &= 2\pi - \alpha+2\\
iv &= \frac{(\pi-\alpha)^2}{(2\pi-\alpha)^2}\\
P &= \frac{2\pi(\pi-\alpha)^2}{(2\pi-\alpha+2)^2(2\pi-\alpha)}
\end{align}

So $P$ approaches $\pi^2/(2\pi+2)^2$ or $0.144$ near $\alpha=0$.  This is a Pacman whose mouth is nearly closed.

Comment: Nice idea! Larger $P$ than the two-disk figure-8.

Comment: Really?  I thought we had P for the figure 8 at 1/4=0.25.  Gerhard "Can't Find Where Mistake Is" Paseman, 2017.02.14.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I calculated $r=1/2$, $iv=1/4$, $P=1/8$.

Comment: I think @GerhardPaseman is right, his shape has iv=1/2

Comment: @MattF.: Oh, you are right. Apologies to @ GerhardPaseman.